# Maven Dependencies? Doesn't access servlet - 404 Error

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlets, eclipselink

I have a program that I wrote a couple years ago for a class, and it worked fine. Recently I updated a lot of things - Java, Eclipse, Tomcat, etc. because I haven't been programming in a while. I messed with the dependencies and now I cannot get it to work. It correctly displays the opening jsp, but never makes it to the handling servlet, giving me a 404 error. I think that I must not have the correct dependency for the servlet anymore? I know the program works, so I have not included code for it. The program uses Eclipselink, mySQL, JSP, and Servlets. (Yes, kicking myself for messing with it). These are the dependencies I have. Am I missing one? Have the wrong one? I am not well versed in maven dependencies

```
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.39</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

And my build has:
Apache Tomcat 9
Java jdk 13.1
Maven Dependencies

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: The dependencies look OK. Could you share your web.xml? How is the servlet declared? Do you see any log in tomcat?

Comment: You should set `<scope>provided</scope>` for the servlets and jsp dependencies, as they are already provided by tomcat. Having them duplicated on your `WEB-INF/lib` may be a source of other problems.

Answer (score 0):

Well, dang it all. I have been trying to get this working for 2 days. Decided problem was with Tomcat. Downloaded and reinstalled it all. Port errors. Changed to every number in the world. Cleaned server, updated project, etc. Nothing worked. Kept getting port number error. Finally saw where someone said they fixed it by restarting computer. Last ditch effort and for some godforsaken reason, it worked. SOOOOOO frustrating. Thanks for your help anyway. I should know - when in doubt, reboot.